# Perl pattern matching and use of \k

Tags: regex, perl

I am facing bit difficulty in using `\k` in regular expressions in perl. from following lines i need to get data after `pipemed_tb` into array and skip part before that can anybody help with that. If possible please tell how to use `\k` effectively in following lines.

```
    set stimulusTop pipemed_tb.pipemed1.gtmc1.gthevcpar91.vncunit1
    set stimulusTop pipemed_tb.pipemed1.gtmc1.gthevcpar91.vneunit1
    set stimulusTop vprunit_tb.vprunit1
```

Comment: /\k<set\tstimulusTop>g*/g This seems not working

Answer (score 1):

You must be confusing `\k<n>` back-reference and Perl `\K` preceding match omitting operator. You do not need this here.

Here is a sample program (part of it is redundant just for illustrative purposes):

```
my @vals = ();
push(@vals, "set stimulusTop pipemed_tb.pipemed1.gtmc1.gthevcpar91.vncunit1");
push(@vals, "set stimulusTop pipemed_tb.pipemed1.gtmc1.gthevcpar91.vneunit1");
push(@vals, "set stimulusTop vprunit_tb.vprunit1");

foreach my $i (@vals) {
  $i =~ s/set stimulusTop //g;
  print $i."\n";  
}
```

Output:

```
pipemed_tb.pipemed1.gtmc1.gthevcpar91.vncunit1                                                                                                                      
pipemed_tb.pipemed1.gtmc1.gthevcpar91.vneunit1                                                                                                                      
vprunit_tb.vprunit1
```

Comment: Thanks stribizhev. I appreciate your help.

Comment: Also can you please tell how to substitute . (dot) by / (forward slash)? I am trying  $j =~ s/.///g; but its throwing an error

Comment: You need to escape dots and slashes like `s/\./\//g`.